# Versioning with Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

We have to implement a versioning system for documents. Each document has an identifier (DOCID), a major and a minor version number. All of this is stored in a table

```
DOCID   MAJOR   MINOR
123     1       0
123     1       1
123     2       0
123     1       2
455     1       0
455     2       0
```

We need to implement a stored proceudre that will take four parameters: whether we want the next major or minor version (VERSION_TYPE), the document ID, the current major version and the current minor version and have to give the next avaialable version number.

For example based on above table if I want a new major version for document 123 I would get 3.0, if I want a new minor version for document 123 for current major version 1 and current minor version 2 I would get 1.2.
If I want to get a version for a new doc id that is not in the system, it has to store the new doc ID and give back major version 1 and minor version 0.

I wrote the below stored procedure but it gives me an error on the last line when I try to execute it:
Cannot insert NULL INTO REVIEW_VERSIONS.DOCID

Any idea what's wrong? Many thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_NEXT_VERSION 
(
  VERSION_TYPE IN VARCHAR2 
, DOC_ID IN VARCHAR2 
, CURRMAJOR IN NUMBER 
, CURRMINOR IN NUMBER
, NEXTMINOR OUT NUMBER
, NEXTMAJOR OUT NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  IF VERSION_TYPE = 'MAJOR' THEN
    NEXTMINOR := 0;
    SELECT MAX(MAJOR)+1 INTO NEXTMAJOR FROM REVIEW_VERSIONS WHERE DOCID= DOC_ID;
    IF NEXTMAJOR IS NULL THEN 
      NEXTMAJOR := 1;
    END IF;
  ELSE IF VERSION_TYPE = 'MINOR' THEN
    NEXTMAJOR := CURRMAJOR;
    SELECT MINOR+1 INTO NEXTMINOR FROM REVIEW_VERSIONS WHERE MAJOR = CURRMAJOR AND DOCID = DOC_ID AND MINOR = (SELECT MAX(MINOR) FROM REVIEW_VERSIONS WHERE MAJOR = CURRMAJOR AND DOCID = DOC_ID);
    IF NEXTMINOR IS NULL THEN 
      NEXTMAJOR := 1; 
      NEXTMINOR := 0;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO REVIEW_VERSIONS (DOCID, MAJOR, MINOR) VALUES (DOC_ID, NEXTMAJOR, NEXTMINOR);
END GET_NEXT_VERSION;
```

Comment: Your `ELSE IF` should be `ELSIF`

Comment: Thanks but that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: It will, check you did it right

Comment: You are right, it did, now it complains about the number and types of parameters when I try to execute it.:(

Comment: How are you executing it?  Separate issues: (1) you need to use `is null` not `= null` (2) a `case` block must have an `else` clause or you will get `ORA-06592: CASE not found while executing CASE statement`.

Comment: Replaced case with IF already, and that seems to be working. I also managed to execute it. Fixed IS NULL as well, thanks. Now, when I try to change it I get a cannot insert NULL into ... error because NEXTMAJOR should never be null

Answer (score 0):

Last seen code:  When VERSION_TYPE = 'MINOR', you assign NEXTMAJOR := CURRMAJOR, but never check to see if CURRMAJOR is NULL.

You may wish to define DEFAULT values in the parameter statement.